# Modify an item of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have added several elements to an ObservableCollection and now I want to modify one of them like:

```
_MyCollection[num].Data1 = someText;
```

As an example, according to code below, intention is: `_MyCollection[5].Type = changedText;`

```
_MyCollection.Add(new MyData
{
    Boundary = Text1,
    Type = Text2,
    Option = Text3
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800091/how-do-i-update-an-existing-element-of-an-observablecollection

Comment: What's the problem with `_MyCollection[5].Type = changedText;`? That should work just fine unless `MyData` is a struct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you just want to see the changes right?
This has nothing to do with the ObservableCollection but with your `MyData` object.
It has to implement `INotifyPropertyChange` - if you do, you will see the changes you made.

```
public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string type;
    public string Type
    {
      get { return type; }
      set
      {
         if (value != type)
         {
            type = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Type");
         }
      }
    }

    // ... more properties

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but what is the related code. Is it like: `MyData[num].Type = changedText`?

Answer (score 1):

This will fire a `CollectionChanged` event:

```
MyData temp = _MyCollection[index];
temp.Type = changedText;
_MyCollection.SetItem(index, temp);
```

Comment: true - this will work too - but if the collection is big the bound wpf-itemcontrol will have to do additional work when you only want to change the values of an item - you should not do this

Comment: Yes, maybe not the best solution; however, if you don't have the option of modifying the `MyData` class to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` this will work.